# Need help creating a complicated UIView - Swift xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiview, swift4

I need some help creating a complicated UIView. In the view, I have a UITextField and a label. These work fine. Below this, I want to add a view to my view that it a UITableView. I want to use the same data in this UITableView as I had in another UITableViewController. Here is my code for the view:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews() {

    //Setup View
    self.backgroundColor = .white

    //Add Subviews
    self.addSubview(textField)
    self.addSubview(nameLabel)

    //Add Constraints
    //Add Constraints
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-|", views: textField)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-150-[v0(75)]|", views: textField)


    nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.leadingAnchor, constant: 3).isActive = true
    nameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.topAnchor, constant: -3).isActive = true

}


//Add Items
let textField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
    textField.placeholder = "List Name"
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 27) // Make relative to height!!
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done //Sets Return Key text to "Done"
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textField
}()

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "NAME"
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer I do not know how to add a TableViewController as a view in this view class.

Comment: The same way you added a label and a textfield

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Just add sub view the item from the other class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
let tableView = UITableView()
// keep the reference to data source
let tableViewDataSource = CustomDataSource()

func setupViews() {
    self.addSubview(tableView)

    // constraints to define its size and position (remember that unlike UILabel and UITextField, UITableView does not have intrinsic content size)
}

let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    // setup data source
    tableView.dataSource = tableViewDataSource
    // other configuration
    return tableView
}()
```

Regarding the tableView dataSource, you basically need to implement the same methods that you already did in that `TableViewController` with which you want to share the table.

```
class CustomDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // code from tableViewController
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // code from tableViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to get the data from the other class to load in the tableView here. The tableView shows but it is empty. @MilanNosáľ

Comment: @NikolasIoannou you need to implement a datasource and set it to the table view

Comment: How do I implement a data source and in which class. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Ill write it a bit later

Comment: Ok, sounds good.

Comment: @NikolasIoannou basically you have to implement the same data source methods that you already implemented for tableView controller.. I have updated the answer to give you some basic direction

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks for helping me out!  @MilanNosáľ

Comment: actually, this worked really well for one of my UITableViews. However, I have another table view that is not working very well. Here is the problem: My first UITableView (which works) is a list of shopping lists. When an item is selected in the first UITableView I use this code set two variable,            
        ItemsVC.selectedName = lists[indexPath.row].name   
        ItemsVC.selectedItems = lists[indexPath.row].items
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ItemsVC, animated: true)              Then I want to use these variables to create a new UITableView.

Comment: This UITableViews cells would display selected items, however, selected Items is set to nil when it needs to be accessed. Could you help. Thanks